# Discovering a chromecast not in current network

Tags: android, networking, chromecast

Initially the Chromecast acts as a 'Access point' to which our mobile app connects. But how does the app figure out that a access point is actually a 'Chromecast', because there might be multiple access points available for the mobile to connect to. What protocol is used to figure out that a access point is  indeed a 'Chromecast' device

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast uses mDNS for device discovery, where devices respond to a request for a particular domain name pattern that other devices wouldn't respond to ... hence, any responding devices (whose responses also include more info in the response, including their friendly name) are listed as available. This is why devices have to be on the same WiFi network ... so that mDNS will work properly (well, with the exception of guest mode, in which discovery happens via a WiFi beacon and pairing happens with an ultrasonic pin code exchange).

Comment: That is not the case; mDNS can only be used "after" chromecast has joined the network and not before; the question was about before joining happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are some message exchanges that only a real chromeast can respond to; that allows identifying a chromecast.